# SEO and the use of ellipsis CSS property

Tags: seo, html, google-search, css, hidden-text

I have a Q&A service and in every question details page, there is a section named "related questions". Every question in there has the title and the initial lines of the answer. We are limiting this through CSS ellipsis property but on the HTML we are adding the entire answer.

- Is it possible that Google doesn't like this?
- I mean, that we are trying to index content that we are not showing entirely?

Note: The answer length can be up to 2000 characters long!

Comment: While I do not have an answer for you, I can say this; Google does fetch (confirmed) and is presumed (believed) to index the entire page. I do know that Google will index fairly large pages properly.

Comment: ...although Google does not (should not) index content that the user does not see.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean with "Google doesn't like this" then this could mean that Google may see it as a form of cloaking, then no, Google just indexes the  whole page.

The question you should ask yourself, is whether or not those related questions and answers are really enough related to the page's topic. If no, then you will be better of if you do not publish those elements. Because, this could make your page(s) less relevant.

But, if related elements are really related and thematically relevant, publish them, no problem. Or, if you want move your visitors to read the related elements on their own pages, use truncating.

*Create for all full answers a variable like:*

```
<?php
    $related = "full answer text;
?>
```

*If you implement it on other pages like related, do it with something like:*

```
<?php
    echo substr($related, 0, 15);
?>
```

Comment: Unless there are very long words, or there is a strict need to end at *exactly* X amount of chars, then end `substr` on a space to prevent words from being cut off: `echo substr($related, 0, strpos($related, ' ', 15)) . ' ...';`. This is a bit better for SEO too since a potential keyword won't be guillotined in half. Also you can add the `...` right at the function instead of using pseudo CSS ellipsis.